# addEventListener and getEventListeners

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

```
var handler = function(){}  
var evt = "test";
el.addEventListener(evt, handler, false);
```

After `addEventListener`, we've attached an event to the element.
but how do I get the event information attaching to the element?
I know the way from Chrome DevTool API: `getEventListeners`,
How do I get event information from DOM API?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard, cross browser way to get a list of existing event listeners.

Some libraries (like jQuery) implement their own way of doing this, but it only works for event handlers that are added via the library.

If you could replace all your `addEventListener()` calls with your own function call, then you could keep track of event listeners yourself in your own data structures.

---

Perhaps if you explain why you're trying to do this, we might be able to help with some sort of different way of solving your problem.

Comment: Okay, I will keep track of these events by myself.  
I just wanna to know whether there is a standard way of doing this.
thanks.

Comment: @user2967890 - since it looks like you're new here, are you aware that when you ask a question and get answers that help, you should select on of the answers as the "best answer" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will both reward the person who provided that answer and earn you some reputation points.